# ArcPy 64bit giving 0xC0000005 error with PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, installation, python-2.7, 64bit, pycharm

I have a simple script, which converts raster to shapefile and merges all the shapefiles. It does not really matter. The execution is fine, everything finishes but:

I am using PyCharm Community 2018.1, when the script finishes I get a window with:

> Python.exe stopped working

which I have to click and close and after that I get an error in PyCharm which says:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

If I run the script on another computer with same setup, same copy of python, everything works just fine and PyCharm says:

> Process finished with exit code 0

I tried a clean install of ArcPy 10.6 x64 background GP, copy the python installation from other PC, same error.

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise (i7, 32GB RAM - I do not think it is important information)

If I make an error in script, where it exits, there is also the traceback + again the same error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

On the other computer it says:

> Process finished with exit code -1

What is funny, if I use 32 bit interpreter, it works just fine. But this is a workstation and I don't really want to use 32 bit version.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Sample of script (as I said, eveything here finishes and I get my final shapefile):

```
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(OFP_folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('10000.tif'):
                list_of_files.append(os.sep.join([dirpath, filename]))

    print list_of_files

    for file in list_of_files:
        print "Working on: {}".format(file)
        create_shape(file)


    list_shp = glob.glob(out + "*.shp")
    print "Merging"
    arcpy.Merge_management(list_shp, out + "MaxOFP.shp")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to sort out the issue by downloading an [ArcGIS (Desktop, Engine) Background Geoprocessing 64-bit Arcpy Exit and Shutdown Patch](https://support.esri.com/en/download/7579) from the Esri website, which addresses this issue.